# When running the test it is trying drop the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, integration-testing

```
bundle exec rake test TEST=test/integration/admin.rb
```

This is the command I am giving to run the integration test. But that file is not loading in the command prompt it showing the error:

> ActiveRecord::JDBCError:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot drop database
>   "DSH_test_ontash_new" because it is currently in use

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a Rails server or console running in a separate shell or database management application, which will prevent you from being able to drop the database.

Make sure you have terminated all connections to that database and try again. Hard to say more with the information given.